# Create Issuer for cert-manager for Rancher 2.x launched with docker-compose

Tags: docker, kubernetes, lets-encrypt, rancher, kubernetes-helm

I am testing Rancher 2 as a Kubernetes interface. Rancher 2 is launched with docker-compose, using image rancher/rancher:latest.

Everything is Ok for clusters, nodes, pods. Then I try to secure some load balancers with certificates. Do do so, I install cert-manager from the catalog/helm.

[image]

I have tried to follow this video tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xc8Jg9ItDVk) which explains how to create an issuer and a certificate, and how to link it to a load balancer.

I create a file for the issuer :

```
apiVersion: certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: root@example.com
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-private-key
    http01: {}
```

It's time to create the issuer.

```
sudo docker-compose exec rancher bash
```

I am connected to the Rancher container. `kubectl` and `helm` are installed.

I try to create the issuer :

```
kubectl create -f etc/cert-manager/cluster-issuer.yaml
error: unable to recognize "etc/cert-manager/cluster-issuer.yaml": no matches for certmanager.k8s.io/, Kind=ClusterIssuer
```

Additional informations :

When I do `helm list`:

```
Error: could not find a ready tiller pod
```

I get the pods to find tiller :

```
kubectl get pods
NAME                             READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
tiller-deploy-6ffc49c5df-zbjg8   0/1       Pending   0          39m
```

I describe this pod :

```
kubectl describe pod tiller-deploy-6ffc49c5df-zbjg8
Name:           tiller-deploy-6ffc49c5df-zbjg8
Namespace:      default
Node:           <none>
Labels:         app=helm
                name=tiller
                pod-template-hash=2997057189
Annotations:    kubernetes.io/created-by={"kind":"SerializedReference","apiVersion":"v1","reference":{"kind":"ReplicaSet","namespace":"default","name":"tiller-deploy-6ffc49c5df","uid":"46f74523-7f8f-11e8-9d04-0242ac1...
Status:         Pending
IP:
Created By:     ReplicaSet/tiller-deploy-6ffc49c5df
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/tiller-deploy-6ffc49c5df
Containers:
  tiller:
    Image:      gcr.io/kubernetes-helm/tiller:v2.8.0-rancher3
    Ports:      44134/TCP, 44135/TCP
    Liveness:   http-get http://:44135/liveness delay=1s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:  http-get http://:44135/readiness delay=1s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      TILLER_NAMESPACE:    default
      TILLER_HISTORY_MAX:  0
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from tiller-token-hbfgz (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  PodScheduled   False
Volumes:
  tiller-token-hbfgz:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  tiller-token-hbfgz
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.alpha.kubernetes.io/notReady:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.alpha.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                 From               Message
  ----     ------            ----                ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  4m (x125 over 39m)  default-scheduler  no nodes available to schedule pods
```

This problem is a bit specific : rancher/kubernetes/docker-compose ... If anyone has some ideas, you're welcome ;)

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You man find answers on dedicated [Rancher forum](https://forums.rancher.com).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found an information to unblock the situation.

Thanks to https://www.idealcoders.com/posts/rancher/2018/06/rancher-2-x-and-lets-encrypt-with-cert-manager-and-nginx-ingress/

The first step is to load the cluster's configuration. I was working on the default cluster. So,

1. I execute bash into the docker container,
2. I load the config file `/root/.kube/config`
3. Update the configuration
4. Go on ... The issuer is correctly created.

If it can help someone ;)